# How can I make this javascript dynamic dom creation function stateless?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, recursion

I have been working on this problem and have figured out a solution.

```js
const TREE_DATA = {
       "widgetData":[
          {
             "label":"node1",
             "color":"red",
             "children":[
                {
                   "label":"vip1",
                   "color":"red",
                   "children":[
                      {
                         "label":"obj1",
                         "color":"gray",
                         "id":"539803eae4b0ffad82491508"
                      },
                      {
                         "label":"obj2",
                         "color":"green",
                         "id":"5395635ee4b071f136e4b691"
                      },
                      {
                         "label":"obj3",
                         "color":"green",
                         "id":"539803e4e4b0ffad82491507"
                      }
                   ],
                   "id":"53956358e4b071f136e4b690"
                },
                {
                   "label":"vip2",
                   "color":"blue",
                   "id":"539803f2e4b0ffad82491509"
                }
             ],
             "id":"5395634ee4b071f136e4b68e"
          },
          {
             "label":"node2",
             "children":[
                {
                   "label":"vip1",
                   "color":"green",
                   "id":"539803eae4b0ffad82491501"
                },
                {
                   "label":"vip2",
                   "color":"green",
                   "id":"5395635ee4b071f136e4b694"
                }
             ],
             "id":"5395637fe4b071f136e4b692"
          },
          {
             "label":"node3",
             "color":"red",
             "children":[

             ],
             "id":"53956371f136e4b692"
          },
          {
             "label":"node4",
             "color":"red",
             "children":[

             ],
             "id":"5656"
          },
          {
             "label":"node5",
             "color":"red",
             "children":[
             ],
             "id":"5395637fe4b071f13b692"
          }
       ]
    }

const createDOM = (arr) => {
  
  function updateDOM(arr, html, el) {
  if (typeof (html) === 'undefined') {
        var html = '';
    }
    if (typeof (el) === 'undefined') {
        var el = {li: '<li>', liEnd: '</li>', ul: '<ul>', ulEnd: '</ul>'};
    }
    if (typeof (arr) === 'string') {
        return el.li + arr + el.liEnd;
    } else if (typeof (arr) === 'object') {
        for (var item in arr) {

            if (typeof (arr[item]) === 'string') {
                html += el.ul 
                          + el.li + arr[item] + el.liEnd 
                        + el.ulEnd;
            } else if(typeof (item) === 'string' && (isNaN(item))){
              html += el.ul 
                        + updateDOM(arr[item],'',el) 
                      + el.ulEnd;
              
            } else if (typeof (arr[item]) === 'object') {
               html = updateDOM(arr[item], html,el);
            }
        }
    }
    return html;
  }
  document.getElementById('tree').innerHTML =  updateDOM(arr);
  
}


createDOM(TREE_DATA);
```

```html
<div id="tree"></div>
```

However, I want to understand how to make it stateless? As in, if I want to pass only TREE_DATA into the inner updateDOM function and return dom tree, how can i do that? I want to be able to compose this function in such a way that I do not have to pass HTML in each recursive function call.How to handle the intermediate HTML?

For example, the below fibonacci function is composed:

```
function factorial(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
   return 1;
  } else {
   return n * factorial(n-1);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want the extra `<ul>`s in the output. If you do, it's easy to change.

You don't need to define `el` in the function. Since it's constant and more like a utility lookup, you can define it outside the function. You could also just inline the HMTML tags.

To make this work by only passing in the tree, you need to return something with each call and append that to the results of previous calls. You can append to a single html string in the for loop and pass found elements in recursively. I've simplified the inner call a bit by testing for an array with `Array.isArray()`, but you should be able to keep your own logic if you want:

```js
const TREE_DATA = {"widgetData":[{"label":"node1","color":"red","children":[{"label":"vip1","color":"red","children":[{"label":"obj1","color":"gray","id":"539803eae4b0ffad82491508"},{"label":"obj2","color":"green","id":"5395635ee4b071f136e4b691"},{"label":"obj3","color":"green","id":"539803e4e4b0ffad82491507"}],"id":"53956358e4b071f136e4b690"},{"label":"vip2","color":"blue","id":"539803f2e4b0ffad82491509"}],"id":"5395634ee4b071f136e4b68e"},{"label":"node2","children":[{"label":"vip1","color":"green","id":"539803eae4b0ffad82491501"},{"label":"vip2","color":"green","id":"5395635ee4b071f136e4b694"}],"id":"5395637fe4b071f136e4b692"},{"label":"node3","color":"red","children":[],"id":"53956371f136e4b692"},{"label":"node4","color":"red","children":[],"id":"5656"},{"label":"node5","color":"red","children":[],"id":"5395637fe4b071f13b692"}]}

var el = { li: '<li>', liEnd: '</li>', ul: '<ul>', ulEnd: '</ul>'};

const createDOM = (arr) => {
  if (typeof(arr) === 'string') {
    return el.li + arr + el.liEnd;
  } else if (typeof(arr) === 'object') {
    let html = ''
    for (var item in arr) {
      if (Array.isArray(arr[item])) {
        html += el.ul + createDOM(arr[item]) + el.ulEnd
      } else {
        html += createDOM(arr[item]);
      }
    }
    return html
  }
  
}

document.getElementById('tree').innerHTML = createDOM(TREE_DATA)
```

```html
<div id="tree"></div>
```

If you're willing to use `reduce()` and `Object.values` you simplify this into something perhaps a little more readable:

```js
const TREE_DATA = {"widgetData":[{"label":"node1","color":"red","children":[{"label":"vip1","color":"red","children":[{"label":"obj1","color":"gray","id":"539803eae4b0ffad82491508"},{"label":"obj2","color":"green","id":"5395635ee4b071f136e4b691"},{"label":"obj3","color":"green","id":"539803e4e4b0ffad82491507"}],"id":"53956358e4b071f136e4b690"},{"label":"vip2","color":"blue","id":"539803f2e4b0ffad82491509"}],"id":"5395634ee4b071f136e4b68e"},{"label":"node2","children":[{"label":"vip1","color":"green","id":"539803eae4b0ffad82491501"},{"label":"vip2","color":"green","id":"5395635ee4b071f136e4b694"}],"id":"5395637fe4b071f136e4b692"},{"label":"node3","color":"red","children":[],"id":"53956371f136e4b692"},{"label":"node4","color":"red","children":[],"id":"5656"},{"label":"node5","color":"red","children":[],"id":"5395637fe4b071f13b692"}]}


const createDOM = (arr) => {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    return arr.reduce((html_string, item) => html_string + "<ul>" + createDOM(item) +  "</ul>", '')
  }
  else if (typeof (arr) === 'object') {
    return Object.values(arr).reduce((html_string, val) => html_string + createDOM(val), '')  
  } 
  else return "<li>" + arr + "</li>";
}


document.getElementById('tree').innerHTML = createDOM(TREE_DATA)
```

```html
<div id="tree"></div>
```

**EDIT**

To use the DOM instead of a string, you basically to the same thing, but spend to dom elements rather than strings.

```js
const TREE_DATA = {"widgetData":[{"label":"node1","color":"red","children":[{"label":"vip1","color":"red","children":[{"label":"obj1","color":"gray","id":"539803eae4b0ffad82491508"},{"label":"obj2","color":"green","id":"5395635ee4b071f136e4b691"},{"label":"obj3","color":"green","id":"539803e4e4b0ffad82491507"}],"id":"53956358e4b071f136e4b690"},{"label":"vip2","color":"blue","id":"539803f2e4b0ffad82491509"}],"id":"5395634ee4b071f136e4b68e"},{"label":"node2","children":[{"label":"vip1","color":"green","id":"539803eae4b0ffad82491501"},{"label":"vip2","color":"green","id":"5395635ee4b071f136e4b694"}],"id":"5395637fe4b071f136e4b692"},{"label":"node3","color":"red","children":[],"id":"53956371f136e4b692"},{"label":"node4","color":"red","children":[],"id":"5656"},{"label":"node5","color":"red","children":[],"id":"5395637fe4b071f13b692"}]}


const createDOM = (arr) => {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    return arr.reduce((ul, item) => {
        ul.appendChild(createDOM(item))
        return ul
    }, document.createElement('ul'))
  }
  else if (typeof (arr) === 'object') {
    return Object.values(arr).reduce((dom, val) => {
        dom.appendChild(createDOM(val))
        return dom
    }, document.createDocumentFragment())  
  } 
  else {
      let li = document.createElement('li')
      li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr))
      return li
  }
}


document.getElementById('tree').appendChild(createDOM(TREE_DATA))
```

```html
 <div id="tree"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @mark! How can I convert this function to use DOM api instead of string?

Comment: @novembersky you basically do the same thing. See edit…